# Vector fields commute implies flows can be written as composition of individual flows

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, smooth-manifolds, vector-fields

> Problem: Let $V, W$ be two complete vector fields, with $[V, W] = 0$. Denote $\Phi^V_t$ and $\Phi^W_t$ as the flows of the two vector fields respectively. Prove that $\Phi^{V+W}_t = \Phi^V_t \Phi^W_t$.

Attempt: this seems like a simple exercise of the relationship between vector fields and flows but I was not able to get the exact answer and use the fact that the two vector fields commute, so please point out mistake/missing steps in my solution please.

My calculations: $\partial_t|_{t=0}(\Phi^V_t \Phi^W_t)(x) = (\partial_t|_{t=0} \Phi^V(t,\Phi^W(t=0, x))) + (\partial_y|_{y=\Phi{^W(t=0,x) = x}} \Phi^V(t,y))(\partial_t|_{t=0} \Phi^W(t,x)) = V_{x} + (\partial_y|_{y=x} \Phi^V(t,y))W_x$

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: HINT: Show that $\phi^V\circ\phi^W$ solves the ODE $u'=(V+W)u$.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro could you elaborate on it a bit more? I know that by definition I should show the ODE is satisfied by the composition, but for some reason the derivative I computed looks really strange... thanks.

Comment: Right, it is a bit trickier than that. Sorry my hint is misleading. I checked Spivak's book and he does a more careful computation, it is at pagg.157-158 of his differential geometry book, volume 1.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro ah I see, guess the calculation is more complicated than I thought. Thanks for the reference.

Comment: What about the following?  We can denote the flows by the exponential map: $\Phi_t^V=\exp(tV)$ and $\Phi_t^U=\exp(tU)$.  By the Baker–Campbell–Hausdorff formula, if $[U,V]=0$, then $\exp(U)\exp(V)=\exp(U+V)$.

Comment: @Doubt thanks for the answer. I will look the formula up.

Answer (score 1):

We can denote the flows by the exponential map: $\Phi_t^V=\exp(tV)$ and $\Phi_t^W=\exp(tW)$.  By the [Baker–Campbell–Hausdorff formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baker%E2%80%93Campbell%E2%80%93Hausdorff_formula#An_explicit_Baker%E2%80%93Campbell%E2%80%93Hausdorff_formula), if $[V,W]=0$, then $$\exp(V)\exp(W)=\exp(V+W).$$ This gives $\Phi_t^V\Phi_t^W=\Phi_t^{V+W}$.

Comment: That's, however, a bit overkill, IMHO. The BCH formula is quite a beast.